# Какие различия имеют два типа условных рендера?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Внутри компонента `<Toggle />` есть свой стейт, а так же инициализация в зависимости от `isOpenInit`.
В случае использование тернарного оператора, один стейт на два компонента, т.е. изменить стейт на одном компоненте, меняется и на другом. (открыли один таб, открыли тоггл, зашли на другой там тоггл открыт, хотя первоначальное состояние `false`).
В случае использование логического `&&` стейты разные и все отрабатывает как должно.

Какие различия имеют 2 типа рендера? (с использованием логического **&&**, с использованием тернарного оператора соответственно)

1)

```
{ indexTab === 0 && (
    <Toggle isOpenInit = {false} /> }

{ indexTab === 1 && (
    <Toggle isOpenInit = {false} /> }
```

2. 

```
{ indexTab === 0 ? (
    <Toggle isOpenInit = {false} /> )

: ( indexTab === 1 && (
    <Toggle isOpenInit = {false} /> ) }
```

Comment: Если вы по условию рендерите абсолютно одинаковые компоненты, значит вы что то делаете не так. Вам нужно решать эту проблему либо на уровнь выше, либо на уровень ниже. Приложите больше кода для понимая полной картины происходящего, а то по коду 2-х условий сложно что-то понять

Comment: Нет никакой разницы, в том, как проверять, что рендерить. Однако `&&` лучше использовать при логике - **показываем этот компонент**, а тернарный для **Какой показать, первый или второй**

Comment: @Алексей Два компонента рендерят абсолютно разный контент и первоначальное состояние открытости\закрытости. Они никак не влияют на суть вопроса, поэтому счел не добавлять лишней информации

Answer (score 0):

Помогло добавление атрибутов `key` в два компонента `<Toggle />` в случае использование тернарного оператора.